# Why is Docker services keep running without my consent

Tags: linux, centos, docker, service, systemctl

These docker services keep running without my consent, how to stop them:

- `/usr/bin/docker-containerd-current`
- `/usr/bin/dockerd-current`

I don't want to uninstall Docker, just want to stop services to reduce used RAM. I'm on CentOS.

Done all these, but those Docker services above launch themselves back:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl disable docker
sudo pkill -f docker
```

Run `top` or `htop` and they are still there.

Comment: How did you install docker? What does `sudo systemctl status docker` show before running stop?

Comment: Possibly some cron/timer is started them.  Perhaps something other service/script is starting them?  Maybe look at your system logs to look to see when it is getting started, and then look backwards and you can see what is starting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that a cron job or a script running from somewhere else that starts it. Look in the cron directories and files and in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/cron` to find what is starting it.

If you just want to stop the service from starting altogether:

```
systemctl mask docker
```

That will link the unit files to `/dev/null` which makes it impossible to start the service.